# On symmetric difference of the Lebesgue measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I found the following proposition in Measure, Integral and Probability from Marek Capinski and Ekkehard Kopp. It concerns the Lebesgue measure space ($X$, $M$, $m$).

> If $A \in M $ and $m(A \triangle B) = 0$ then $B \in M$ and $m(A) = m(B)$.

I managed to prove that the measure of the set $A$ and the measure of the set $B$ are the same since

> $m(A) = m(A \cup B) + m(A \cup B^c) = m(A \cup B) = m(B),$

but I seem to get stuck at proving that $B$ must be in $M$. Anyone that can provide me with a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $E:=A\setminus B$ and $F:=B\setminus A$ are both in $M$ for being a null set.

Now notice that we can write $B$ as
$$B=[A\setminus E] \cup F$$
But then that means...